# How can I remove ONLY punctuation marks like "." and ","?

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to search for specific words like "earnings" or "income". Therefor, I created a wordlist and searched for the words in the text.

However, my code returns no results for the words with an additional punctuation mark like "earnings." or "income,". Now, I want to remove these punctuations without removing a dot in a number like "2.4" or any other marks like "%".

I already tried

```
table = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation})
text_wo_dots = text.translate(table)
```

and

```
text_wo_dots = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',' ',text)
```

but this removed all punctuation.

Comment: Can you add some sample text on which you cannot find the words you want? Also, can you add the code with which you search for the specific words?

Comment: What kind of object are you working with?

Comment: what are your specific search words ? is it only `earnings` and `income` ?

Comment: @Ralf: I searched for the words with 

            count_earnings=0
            for i in text:
                if i in earnings:
                    count_earnings += 1

My wordlist is earnings=["ebit", "ebitda", "eps", "earning", "earnings", "income", "profit", "profits", "ebt", "result", "results"].

And the following text is an example where my code doesn't give a result:
"is targeting a further improvement in segment earnings, with sales volumes"

The text is in a txt-file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, you first split your text into seperate words, including the punctution marks

```
text = ["This is an example, it contains 1.0 number and some words."]
raw_list = text.split()
```

Now you can remove the punctuation marks that are at the end of an element.

```
cleaned_words = []
for word in raw_list:
    if word[-1] in ['.', ',', '!', '?']:
        cleaned_words.append(word[:-1])
    else:
        cleaned_words.append(word)
```

*Note 1:* If your text contains numbers like `1.` for `1.0` you also need to take the second last character into account and leave the point in if `isdigit()` evaluates to `True`
*Note 2:* if There are sentences that end with multiple punctuation marks you should run a while loop to remove them and then only append once no more ounctuation marks are found.

```
while True:
    if word[-1] in ['.', ',', '!', '?']:
        word = word[:-1]
    else:
        break

cleaned_words.append(word)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this might also work:

`[\.,:!?][\n\s]`

`[\.,:!?]` contains some punctuation marks, you can add more if needed, while `[\n\s]` means that it must be followed by a space or a newline character.

Here is a working example: https://regex101.com/r/TcR6Ct/2

Below is the Python code:

```
import re

s = 'Bla, bla, bla 7.6 bla.'

pattern = '[\.,:!?][\n\s]'
s = re.sub(pattern, '', s+' ')
print(s)
```

Comment: This works also fine, but there has to be an additional space, otherwise the output would be 'Blablabla 7.6 bla'

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a negative lookahead `(?!` and a negative lookbehind `(?<!` to assert what is directly on the left and what is directly on the right is not a digit:

```
(?<!\d)[^\w\s]+(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XYOV7L/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7XAuVM)

For example:

```
import re
text = "income,and 4.6 test"
text_wo_dots = re.sub(r'(?<!\d)[^\w\s]+(?!\d)',' ',text)
print(text_wo_dots) # income and 4.6 test
```